# Microsoft Access Query through VBA gets repeated?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got this query in my form:

```
strSQL = "SELECT cityID FROM City WHERE Name =" & Chr(34) & Me.List60.Value & Chr(34) & ";"
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("QueryCityName", strSQL)
DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name
Me.cityID = qdf
```

What i want to do is run the following query (the List60 value is dynamic) and assign the result to a textbox. Now the query runs flawless the first time and the second is spuwing error about duplicate query (i check there is a new query saved in Querys with the used value). So here are my question:

How to avoid saving the query and making it always dynamic?
How to assign the result from this query to a textbox (i mean qdf.Value in the example is not working)?

Answer (score 2):

You should not create a query without checking if it exists or you will get an error, as you have found. You can change the sql by referencing the querydef, you do not need to create a new query. However, in this situation, you do not need a query, just DLookUp.

```
DLookUp("cityID", "City", "Name ='" & Replace(Me.List60.Value,"'","''") & "'")
```

You can set a textbox control source to Dlookup like so:

```
=DLookUp("cityID", "City", "Name ='" & Replace(List60.Value,"'","''") & "'")
```

BTW Name is a reserved word and should not be used anywhere, it will cause untold grief.

Comment: Thanks but i found myself a better solution fixing both of my problems.

Comment: What's the better solution? I think @Remou's is by far the simplest, but I'd love to hear about something easier. If you're referring to the answer you posted, it's not even close to be simpler or easier that @Remou's answer, and I'd consider it to be definitely a substandard and overcomplicated way of getting the result.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with even less code:

```
strSQL = "SELECT cityID FROM City WHERE Name =" & Chr(34) & Me.List60.Value & Chr(34) & ";"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Now if everyone have the same issue, just use:

```
rst![name_of_the_row_in_your_table]
```

In my case this is the whole piece:

```
strSQL = "SELECT cityID FROM City WHERE Name =" & Chr(34) & Me.List60.Value & Chr(34) & ";"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
Me.cityID = rst![cityID]
```

Comment: I think you will find that the solution I suggested does not require any code, and if code is used, only one line.

Comment: This solution is definitely not superior to @Remou's answer at all.